# cron jobs process_membership, send_reminder and process_membership_reminder_date

Tags: civimember, cron-job, scheduled-reminders

I want to send out membership reminders 6 weeks, 3 weeks, etcetera before membership lapses. To send them out, i see multiple cron jobs:

- process_membership, named Update Membership Statuses and Send Renewal
  Reminders
- send_reminder, named Send Scheduled Reminders, and
- process_membership_reminder_date, named Set Renewal Reminder Dates

The first one should be on, I guess, like daily or so ?
It may depend on the second one - not sure ?
The 3rd one comes with a warning that it should be off:

```
WARNING: Membership renewal reminders have been migrated to the Schedule Reminders functionality
```

indicating that perhaps the first one doesnt have to be on at all.

I'm all confused :-) How do I set this up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one, *process_membership*, goes around and updates the membership statuses.  It's what sets a member's status to "expired" once the end date comes around.  Once upon a time, it sent reminders, but it doesn't anymore (new installations don't have that label for the job).  You should be able to have it run daily.

The second one, *send_reminder*, is for all reminders--activity, event, birthday, etc. in addition to memberships.  Although you could get away with running it daily, you should run this hourly, because you may have time-sensitive reminders set up for events.

Once you have the job running, you should go into the Scheduled Reminders admin page and set up the appropriate reminders.

The third one, *process_membership_reminder_date*, should stay disabled--it's obsolete, as the warning says.  You could even delete it if you like.

Comment: wtf .. i was going to delete process_membership_reminder_date .. but its gone today. and the label for process_membership has changed. I had to come back here to see what I wrote yesterday. hm, whatever happened, i suppose its good.